# How to access tflite model from Tensorflow Java API?

Tags: android, tensorflow, tensorflow-lite, java

I have a tflite model that I am using in Android for Handwriting Recognition. I want to implement the same in my backend using Java.

I tried using the same Android libraries and also used TensorFlow and tried to import using SavedModelBundle but these are not working

How do I achieve this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which tensorflow version you are using?

Comment: @kruxx The tensorflow version is 1.13.1

Comment: Try to follow [this](https://github.com/tensorflow/examples/blob/master/lite/examples/image_classification/android/README.md) example.

Comment: @kruxx I have done it using Android. I want to do the same using TensorFlow's Java Backend dependency.

Answer (score 0):

You can build tflite for your backend, especially if it runs Linux. Don't expect performance to be server-grade, because the C++ code is only optimized for mobile platforms, and does not employ CUDA et al.